# Scrapy - Splitting selector parts between two variables

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-shell

I'm having issues **scraping** data using my spider script even though a similar code works when I test it in the scrapy shell. The only difference is that in my script I am splitting the selector.

Here is the selector that works in the shell:

```
(//tr[position()>2]/td[position()=2])[1]
```

And here is the selector in the script:

```
def parse_forsale(self, response):
        listingdata = response.xpath(".//tr[position()>2]")  # < PART 1 OF SELECTOR
        for data in listingdata:
            A = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][1]").get() # < PART 2 OF SELECTOR
            B = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][2]").get()
            C = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][3]").get()
            D = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][4]").get()
            E = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][5]").get()
            F = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][6]").get()
            G = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][7]").get()
            H = data.xpath(".//td[position()=2][8]").get()
```

My educated guess for why this is not working is because when I'm using the selector in the shell I can put parentheses before the "//" and right before "[1]", which helps the selector work properly. However in the script I can't do this because I'm splitting the two components.

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is a shorter way to write `td[position()=2]`:

```
td[2]
```

Next what did you mean by this XPath:

```
.//td[position()=2][1]
```

Select `td` at **second** position (`position()=2`) that is at the **first** (`[1]`)position at the **same time**?

**UPDATE** If you just want to process all rows after second and need to read `td[2]`:

```
//tr[position() > 2]/td[2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on td[2], looks much cleaner. As for your question, I think you identified the problem. So the full selector is "//tr[>2]/td[2]". What I was trying to do is make it loop through so it gets A = //tr[**3**]/td[2], B = //tr[**4**]/td[2], C = //tr[**5**]/td[2], etc. Any idea on how can I modify the script so it assigns each subsequent tr element to the next variable?